# MS SQL job is running well but it will take double time as per given time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I was created a job in MS-SQL Server Agent which running schedule is every 10 minutes time. But it run after 20 minutes continuously. What I did wrong in setting? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJbjW.jpg)

Comment: It's hard to tell unless we can see the SQL/SQL agent set up! Please provide more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the start and completion time of the first job. If job takes longer than 10 minutes, it can not invoke the job within that time slot. So, i assume job invokes after first finishes.

Ven

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi Sagar,

can you also check Date settings on your SQL server please. Also please attach recent history of the job.

Regards